# jBrowserDriver get call hangs

Tags: java, snapshot, headless

This might be a small configuration issue, just that i have not been successful in finding the issue.

I am using jBrowserDriver to get a snapshot an ajax-enabled page.

My configuration for the WebClient is :-

```
    Builder builder = Settings.builder();

    builder.headless(true);
    builder.javascript(true);
    builder.quickRender(true);
    builder.timezone(Timezone.ASIA_CALCUTTA);
    builder.userAgent(UserAgent.CHROME);

    JBrowserDriver jbd = new JBrowserDriver(builder.build());
```

As soon as a call is made to jbd.get(url), the code hangs. This doesnt happen on my mac os x, but happens on the linux server.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks!

Comment: No responses :(

Can we somehow disable CSS rendering on server end. I just need the html prepared according to the javascript. Somebody, please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it is now resolved. To see if you have the same issue make add this do your builder

```
builder.javaOptions("-Dquantum.verbose=true", "-Dprism.verbose=true", "-verbose", "-verbose:class", "-Dprism.useFontConfig=false")
```

Then run your app, when it hangs up look at your log files and if you see this error:

```
[2016-12-01T16:17:32.329][Instance 1][Port 38914] Error: JavaFX detected no fonts! Please refer to release notes for proper font configuration
```

If you do then add this to your builder (and remove the previous line or your log files will get huge)

```
builder.javaOptions("-Dprism.useFontConfig=false")
```

Comment: @user3279692 did it work for you? I got the same error and using those options makes no difference at all. It just keeps frozen.